# Corrupted pen drive formatting error

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-drive

I have a 32GB pen drive i have inserted the pen drive but its not showing up (USB not recognised). I checked it in the disks window it is showing up there, but showing the size to be 4.2 MB. I have tried many ways to format the pen drive but was not able to. Can you help me out with this

Thanks.

Comment: You should include what exactly you've tried to format the device, as we weren't there when you did that and could only guess what you haven't tried to give you a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the partition table of the USB drive is corrupted.
By "disks window" I assume you are talking about [`gnome-disks-utility`](https://apps.gnome.org/app/org.gnome.DiskUtility/), if so then:

## NOTE: All data on the USB disk will be erased!

1. Click on 3 dots around the top right corner
2. Click on "Format Disk"
3. Select a partition table accoring to your needs
4. Click on "Format"